# What is the spectral sequence associated to this filtration on the de Rham complex?

Tags: reference-request, derived-functors, spectral-sequences, de-rham-cohomology, filtrations

I am trying to calculate some relative de Rham cohomology, but I am not too skilled with hypercohomology or spectral sequences, and the situation becomes more complicated because (1) the base is not affine, so I need higher direct images instead of sheaf cohomology, and (2) the base is not a field, so the graded pieces of the spectral sequence do not recover the full cohomology.

I have a certain filtration on one of the cohomology groups, but I'm not sure where it fits in a bigger picture. I would be really grateful for some help with this. My primary focus is $H^1_{dR}$, but it would be great to understand more.

Let $\pi: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, and $\Omega_{X/Y}$ the sheaf of relative differentials.

We compute the relative de Rham cohomology as the hypercohomology of the complex $\Omega_{X/Y}^\bullet$.

The hypercohomology can be computed as the cohomology of the total complex $C^\bullet$:
$$C^k = \bigoplus\limits_{i+j=k}C^{i,j}$$
where
$$C^{i,j} := \check{C}^j\left(\mathcal{U}, \Omega^i_{X/Y}\right)$$
is module of $\check{C}$ech $j$-cocycles
for an affine open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$.

In particular
$$C^1 = C^{0,1}\oplus C^{1,0}$$
so $\alpha = (\beta, \gamma) \in C^1$
consists of a term $\beta$ from $\mathcal{O}_X$ of "$\check{C}$ech degree 1" and a term $\gamma$ from $\Omega^1_{X/Y}$ of "$\check{C}$ech degree 0".

The $\check{C}$ech 1-cochains $C^{0,1}$ have a filtration:
$$\text{cochains } \supset \text{ cocycles } \supset \text{ coboundaries } \supset 0$$

and we can lift this filtration to $C^1$ via the projection
$$C^1 = C^{0,1}\oplus C^{1,0} \to C^{0,1}$$
$$\alpha = (\beta, \gamma) \mapsto \beta$$

and this filtration is:
$$\operatorname{Fil}^0C^1 = C^1 $$
$$\operatorname{Fil}^1C^1 = \left\{(\beta,\gamma) \,|\; \beta \in \check{Z}^j(\mathcal{U}, \Omega^i_{X/Y})\right\}$$
$$\operatorname{Fil}^2C^1 = \left\{(\beta,\gamma) \,|\; \beta \in \check{B}^j(\mathcal{U}, \Omega^i_{X/Y})\right\}$$
$$\operatorname{Fil}^3C^1 = 0 $$

I am unsure about this, but I think that, at least when $X \to Y$ is relative dimension 1,
this filtration passes to the 1st de Rham cohomology, and we get a complex
$$R^0\pi_*\Omega_{X/Y} \to H^1_{dR}(X/Y) \to R^1\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X$$

which resembles the short exact sequence one gets from the "filtration bête",
but it is not exact, let alone short exact.
The complex factors into the sequence
$$R^0\pi_*\Omega^1_{X/Y} \to  \operatorname{Fil}^2H^1(X/Y) \to H^1(X/S) \to  \operatorname{Gr}^1H^1(X/Y) \to R^1\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X$$

I must be looking at a small part of a spectral sequence associated to a filtered complex, but I am having trouble matching it to what I see in the literature.

**Questions:**

- What is the natural way to extend this filtration to the whole complex, and not just $C^1$?
- Which filtration and spectral sequence am I dealing with here?
- What exact sequence do I get from the spectral sequence to describe $H^1_{dR}$ (not just the associated graded)?
- Is there a better way to approach the computation of $R^\bullet\pi_*\Omega^\bullet_{X/Y}$? I do intend on generalizing to other complexes, like twisted de Rham, etc.

I would really appreciate any help.